# web.config settings are replaced while debugging

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have 3 web.config files...

```
web.config

web.debug.config

web.release.config
```

If I add a

```
<location path="ForgottPassWord.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This is being removed when I debug? I tried to add the same section to all 3 config files but each time I run debug its removed. How can I have it intact in all 3 files?

Comment: How do you know it's being ignored? It allows all users to that page.

Comment: I can see that this part is not in web.config any more as soon as I hit debug.